# Beamerposter and bookmarks

Tags: beamer, hyperref, bookmarks, beamerposter

I am using a scheme like:

```
\section{<section name>}
\begin{block}{\thesection.  \secname}
% content placed here
\end{block}
```

to achieve panels on a beamer poster.  I would also ideally use

```
\hypersetup{bookmarks=true}
```

in the preamble or otherwise, so that when the poster is opened in a .pdf viewer which supports bookmarks, one could navigate to the panel / section / block of interest.

I suspect that this functionality is working fine, however, I'm realizing that the bookmark functionality may be restricted to page.  Naturally, since all of the content on a poster is on the same page, then selecting different bookmarks in the .pdf viewer will have no observable effect on the document view.

The functionality that I think would be useful is to `zoom to area occupied by content'.  Despite the fact that all content is on the same page, selecting a bookmark would adjust the view, zooming in to encompass the page space occupied by the section associated with the bookmark selected.

Any comments on whether this functionality is supported?

Please see the mwe below:

```
\documentclass[final,professionalfonts]{beamer} % options are 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{fp}%
\usepackage{xkeyval}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
\usepackage{calc}%
\usepackage{multicol}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[size=12pt,%
orientation=landscape,%
size=A0,%
scale=1]%
{beamerposter}%

% declare mode and theme
\mode<presentation>{%
\usetheme{Montpellier}
}%

% define title
\title[]{Poster title}

% define authors
\author{Author}%

% define affiliations
\institute[]{Institute}%

% date
\date{\today}

% define the conference / venue
\def\theconference{Presented at}

% authors email address
\def\theemailaddress{lets.meet@cornern.de}

% authors url address
\def\theurl{}

% figures and tables
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

% define lengths
\newlength{\intrablocksep}
\setlength{\intrablocksep}{0.25cm}

\newlength\MyColSep{}
\setlength\MyColSep{1cm}

\newlength\MyColWd{}
\setlength{\MyColWd}{0.24\textwidth-0.8666666\MyColSep}

% create a double column width
\newlength\MyColWddouble{}
\setlength{\MyColWddouble}{0.36\textwidth+0.8666666\MyColSep}

\newlength\MyColWhalf{}
\setlength{\MyColWhalf}{0.18\textwidth-0.8666666\MyColSep}

\hypersetup{bookmarks=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\small
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}[t]{\MyColWd} % 1
% Abstract
\begin{block}{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{block}
\addvspace{\intrablocksep}
% Background
\section{Background}
\begin{block}{\thesection.  \secname}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{block}
\end{column} % 1

\begin{column}[t]{\MyColWddouble}   % 2
% body section
\section{Body Section}
\begin{block}{\thesection.  \secname}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{block}
\addvspace{\intrablocksep}
% body section
\section{Body Section}
\begin{block}{\thesection.  \secname}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{block}
\end{column} %  2

\begin{column}[t]{\MyColWddouble}   % 3
% body section
\section{Body Section}
\begin{block}{\thesection.  \secname}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{block}
\end{column} % 3
\end{columns} % end poster columns

\end{frame} % end poster

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `bookmark` package. It can do all kind of crazy stuff, like specifying the view (as long as the pdfviewer supports it)

Comment: Can you add a test document so that we have something to start with?

Comment: Certainly can @samcarter, thanks for your interest.

Comment: Is the `blockdiagram` package available somewhere?

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `xcolor` with beamer

Comment: Thanks again, removed both of these unnecessary package references.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I just tested and if a section is outside the currently viewed part of the page, the bookmark will jump to this location automatically. So the remaining problem is zoom....

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  Any comments related to using zoom functionality with the bookmarks package are appreciated.

Comment: I was hoping that something like `\bookmark[dest=LastSection,view={XYZ \calc{.5\paperwidth} \calc{.5\paperheight} 0.5}]{test}` would set the zoom to 50%, but unfortunately it does  not seem to work

Comment: I have looked into the bookmark package and tried a few things with no immediate success.  Opening up for bounty to attract input from a user who may have more experience with the bookmark package and it's application to beamer and beamerposter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could give you a start

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{zref-savepos,expl3,lipsum,xcolor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn\posinbp #1 {\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn{\int_eval:n{#1}sp}{1bp}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\zsavepos{sec1}\textcolor{red}{SEC 1}
\lipsum[1]


\vspace*{3cm}\hspace*{4cm}\zsavepos{sec2}\textcolor{blue}{SEC2}
\lipsum[1]

% +655360 is to move the y coordinate up by 10pt
\bookmark[
 page=1,
 view=XYZ \posinbp{\zposx{sec1}} \posinbp{\zposy{sec1}+655360}  3]{SEC 1}

\bookmark[
 page=1,
 view=XYZ \posinbp{\zposx{sec2}} \posinbp{\zposy{sec2}+655360}  3]{SEC 2}


\end{document}
```

In the adobe reader (in sumatra it doesn't work) I then get this initial view

[image]

And this if I click on the SEC2 bookmark:

[image]

An alternative view could be the `page /FitR left bottom right top` setting. For this use two labels, one at the top left, and one at the bottom right.